# Python 2.7 Get month from 2 months ago (i.e get '05' from todays date)

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this that I have missed with my efforts to find the answer.

Basically how do I get the number of month i.e '05' or '04' from n number of months ago?

Apologies if this was already answered but the questions I researched here could not answer my question.

**Edit**

There is no month parameter in timedelta, so this did not answer my question.

Martin answered my question perfectly!

Comment: @MorganThrapp: that'll not get you a month ago, because months have irregular lengths.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, right, I forgot timedelta doesn't have a month kwarg. I thought it did for some reason.

Comment: I think it is relativedelta that has the month kwarg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With some simple modular arithmetic:

```
from datetime import date

def months_ago(count):
    today = date.today()
    return ((today.month - count - 1) % 12) + 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> date.today()
datetime.date(2015, 7, 28)
>>> for i in range(13):
...     print(months_ago(i))
... 
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
12
11
10
9
8
7
```

Answer (score 4):

While Martijn's answer is perfect for your specific question for anyone who stumbles across this answer looking for a date X months ago rather than just the month's number I would suggest using [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#examples) from the third party module [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/).  I have found it quite helpful:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

>>> today = date.today()
datetime.date(2015, 7, 28)

>>> for i in range(13):
        print(today - relativedelta(months=i))
2015-07-28
2015-06-28
2015-05-28
2015-04-28
2015-03-28
2015-02-28
2015-01-28
2014-12-28
2014-11-28
2014-10-28
2014-09-28
2014-08-28
2014-07-28
```

Comment: Absolutely, this is also helpful to anyone viewing this! Thanks